# Working with py2exe and BeautifulSoup. Script run fine but after converting into .exe , it shows error

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, py2exe, python-module

I have created a script with beautifulSoup to scrap a website. when I am running the script, I got what I wanted to.
So moving on I decided to convert it inot .exe file. Conversion has done except it show that ---
[the following modules appear to be missing '_scproxy', 'builder.parserRejectedMarkup','builder.builder_registry', 'cchardet', 'chardet', 'html.parser', 'htmlslib', 'html5lib', 'iconvz' etc.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMhZy.jpg)

However it created the .exe file and when I tried to run .exe file it shows--

[bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pafuu.jpg)

I tried to uninstall-reinstall the package and tried to search from available content but that doesn't help.
Here is the code for Script(p3_extract.py):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import lxml
url="http://fuckinghomepage.com/"
page= urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup_package = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
p1_soup= soup_package.find("p")
p2_soup = p1_soup.next_sibling
p3_soup = p2_soup.next_sibling
print p3_soup.string
```

and here for setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import lxml
setup(console=['p3_extract.py'])
```

Help me out.( I am doing this on **win10-32bit and python 2.7**.)
Thanks

Comment: I had this problem recently and after a lot of searching I gave up and had to quick fixed by using `html.parser` instead of `lxml`.  No amount of adding includes and packages to py2exe would get it to work for me.  Hopefully you get a real answer here!

Comment: thansk @Jkdc it worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem compiling a project where I was using **lxml** and **selenium** (instead of bs4). The solution is to import packages in your setup.py py2exe options and not to import them in the script as you did...

> 

**Add options to your setup.py**

You can use more [py2exe options](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ListOfOptions) in order to make sure that you are importing all the modules and the packages required by your project. E.g.

```
# setup.py
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=["p3_exctract.py"],
      options={
              "py2exe":{
                    "packages": ["lxml"] # List of the package you want to make sure that will be imported
               }
       }
    )
```

In this way you can force the import of the missing script of your project

Comment: @sajjan-kumar if this answers to your question, can you mark it as closed? Otherwise I would be glad to help you further

Comment: thanks @mabe02 I found a solution (using html.parse instead of lxml) but I also tried your method and it worked.